# Optionally allowing a backbutton event to propagate with cordova

Tags: cordova, events, back-button

Is there any way in cordova 3.x or 4 to allow the backbutton event to propagate to the "normal" handler(s), like you can do with most other user interface events (click, touch etc).

Our problem is that we need to disable the backbutton under certain circumstances, but allow it to perform normal back navigation the rest of the time.

Currently we have added a global click listener, that examines the current situation, and then adds/removes the backbutton listener, depending on what it finds. 
This is fine while events are user driven, but some situations results in the app (for example) popping up a 2nd or 3rd dialog (which is one of the places where the backbutton must be disabled) - this is causing a ruckus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful. Your application might be violating the application guidelines for app stores. The microsoft app store doesn't allow you to prevent the hardware back button from going back, for instance.

In these cases where the user can't proceed or go back, the suggested behavior is to exit the application, preferably after prompting the user that clicking back again will exit the application.

Comment: Valid point about the appstores, did not even think about that. (Un?)fortunately I am in bespoke app hell, so the application in question will never go to an appstore, it will be distributed via alternative channels (OTA, MDM system etc).

Answer (score 1):

if suppose you want to exit from your app only if you are on a home page.then you have to write following line in DeviceReady function.

```
document.addeventlistener("backbutton", onBackButton,false);

   function onBackButton(){
          if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "homepage"){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else{
        navigator.app.backHistory();

    }
```

Comment: Hhmm, assuming the navigator.app.backHistory() can be trusted to do what it should, this might actually works (replacing the first if check of an appropriate "is some modal active" check. Thanks Akshay.